# Forwarding a website without changing the visible URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, web, cname, forwarding

I would like to forward users who visit xyz.com to abc.com/xyz without the URL changing, and without using an iframe. I also want xyz.com/1 to lead to abc.com/xyz/1

Can you help me do this?

**Other details:**

1. The website at abc.com/xyz is a Wordpress site, so I can change the URL to look like xyz.com
2. The main reason for this is that getting hosting on xyz.com is way too expensive for my organization, and abc.com is owned by our parent org which gave us that options

Comment: Is it ok for you to run a proxy server on xyz.com and proxy every request to yours?

Comment: I don't even have a box I can use to run the proxy server

Comment: Are you able to configure the server at `abc.com` in any way? ie. Are you able to add `xyz.com` as an "addon" / "parked" or "alias" domain? Or manually edit the server config to create an additional virtual host?

Comment: Do you have access to the DNS server for abc.com?

Comment: No for both the questions. I have no access to abc.com directly. I have ssh access to abc.com/xyz